# Unable to read CSV file with semicolon in rows. Not able to use drop function in pandas to delete the rows

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to read a csv file that has some semicolons in the rows. I get an error when I try reading the file and not able to proceed. The first 8 lines that contain these semicolons are not of any use to me, so I want to delete the first 8 rows.

These are the first 8 lines of the CSV files that I want to delete

```
;                                   
;  Proficy Historian SDK Data Export                                    
;  Generated: 06/04/2019 01:54:03 PM                                    
;  Start Time: 06/03/2019 02:27:00 PM                                   
;  End Time: 06/04/2019 01:53:00 PM                                 
;  Interval: 60000 milliseconds                                 
;  Records Returned: 1406                                   
;
```

The code I've written below works well when I remove the semicolons from each row.

This is the code I've written:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('89017 SV.csv')
df.drop(df.index[0:8])
```

I get the following error when I use this code -

> "ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 9, saw 10"

Comment: It's pretty clear, it expects 1 field, and saw 10. Prepare your file using `sed` so they are removed.

Answer (score 3):

2 options:

1. use Pandas skiprows option. `df = pd.read_csv('89017 SV.csv', skiprows=8)`
2. use Pandas comment option. `df = pd.read_csv('89017 SV.csv', comment=";")`